# Send Commerce Manager catalog product using WhatsApp Cloud API

Tags: whatsapp

After successfully adding my catalog from Commerce manager to Whatsapp manager, now I want to send the user this product via WhatsApp cloud API, I have seen the link which is related to the on-permises API, but found no luck.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/commerce-guides/share-products-with-customers.

my request body code so far:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages](https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/%7B%7BPhone-Number-ID%7D%7D/messages)

```js
{
"interactive": {
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "9***********",
    "type": "product",
    "body": {
      "text": "text-body-content"
    },
    "footer": {
      "text": "text-footer-content"
    },
    "action": {
      "catalog_id": "11111111111111",
      "product_retailer_id": "2222"
    }
  }
}
```

error:

```js
 {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) The parameter messaging_product is required.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AZ-AFvM-Nsnm62de34st5mMJxzJ"
    }
}
```

**another request**

```js
{ 
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to" : "**********",
  "type": "interactive",
  "interactive": {
    "type": "product",
    "body": {
      "text": "body text"
    },
    "footer": {
      "text": "footer text"
    },
    "action": {
      "catalog_id": "1968701893374783",
      "product_retailer_id": "5493"
    }
  }
}

Result: {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#131009) Parameter value is not valid",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 131009,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "Interactive Message type,  'product' not supported. Supported types ['button', 'list']"
        },
        "error_subcode": 2494010,
        "fbtrace_id": "AntQdhmCkgZ0Xtaz643Bgq"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It is [supporting from Aug 25, 2022](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-platform/changelog#cloud-api---august-25--2022),

> You can now include products and services in messages sent to customers, and customers can add them to shopping carts without having to leave the chat thread. Refer to the Sell Products & Services guide to learn how to send Single and Multi-Product messages to customers.

---

<strike>There is no support for `product` and `product_list` types in [Cloud API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/overview), but you can use it in [On-Premises API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/overview)</strike>,

<strike>Might be it is still in development</strike>, You can track the conversations in Facebook Community,

- [1094784808057904](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1094784808057904/)
- [415039447294216](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/415039447294216/)

Comment: have u experienced that when I am sending my product using WhatsApp cloud API(already set up products in commerce manager and attached it to the WhatsApp manager) it's only visible on Web.Whatsapp whereas the message is not showing in the mobile WhatsApp app?

Comment: I have not implemented it yet, but I saw the same issues in Facebook developer forums, I would suggest you track the same issues there.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": m_id,
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive":

        {
            "type": "product_list",
            "header": {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "header text"
            },
            "body": {
                "text": "body text"
            },
            "footer": {
                "text": "footer text"
            },
            "action": {
                "catalog_id": "catalog id",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "title": "section title",
                        "product_items": [
                            {"product_retailer_id": "product id"},
                        ]},
                    {
                        "title": "section title",
                        "product_items": [
                            {"product_retailer_id": "product id"},
                         
                        ]},
                ]

            },
        }


             }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).